# How to use CONNECT BY in Oracle with columns that contain strings with forward slashes

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I have a table in Oracle 12c Standard Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 with the following sample data

| SECTION | PARENT | CHILD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | FIRST_ENTRY | STRING1/AA1 |
| A | FIRST_ENTRY | STRING2 |
| A | FIRST_ENTRY | STRING3 |
| A | STRING1/AA1 | SUB_STRING1 |
| A | STRING1/AA1 | SUB_STRING2 |
| A | STRING1/B2 | SUB_STRING4 |
| A | STRING1/B2 | SUB_STRING5 |
| A | STRING5 | SUB_STRING5 |
| ... | ... | ... |

When I execute the below query with Oracle Developer Tools for VS Code:

```
SELECT
    SAMPLE_TABLE.PARENT,
    SAMPLE_TABLE.CHILD
FROM
    SAMPLE_TABLE
WHERE
    SAMPLE_TABLE.SECTION1 = 'A'
START WITH
    SAMPLE_TABLE.PARENT = 'FIRST_ENTRY'
CONNECT BY PRIOR
    SAMPLE_TABLE.CHILD = SAMPLE_TABLE.PARENT
```

I get the below result.

| PARENT | CHILD |
| --- | --- |
| FIRST_ENTRY | STRING1/AA1 |
| FIRST_ENTRY | STRING2 |
| FIRST_ENTRY | STRING3 |
| STRING1/AA1 | SUB_STRING1 |
| STRING1/AA1 | SUB_STRING2 |
| STRING1/B2 | SUB_STRING4 |
| STRING1/B2 | SUB_STRING5 |

`STRING1/B2` should not be in the result and it seems to me that the query result is matching on `STRING1` excluding the forward slash and what is after it. When I try the query with strings that do not contain forward slash the result is as expected.

I went through the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Hierarchical-Queries.html#GUID-0118DF1D-B9A9-41EB-8556-C6E7D6A5A84E) for the `CONNECT BY` query, but did no find any solution there.

How to write the above query in a way that matches parent/child taking in account the forward slash and string after it?

Comment: Cannot replicate your problem as `STRING1/B2` is not output by that query for that sample data [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bSXLYV2v)